# not allowed to push to protected [remote rejected] dev_0 -> dev_0 (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, git-branch

I could push to repository, but now git is showing me this error:

```
remote: Gitea: Not allowed to push to protected branch dev_0
To git.us.qwasar.io:quest03_5339_nok2my/quest03.git
 ! [remote rejected] dev_0 -> dev_0 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.us.qwasar.io:quest03_5339_nok2my/quest03.git'
```

why does it even happen? I could push before, but the branch is suddenly protected now.

Comment: `protected branch` is a feature of hosting services like Gitlab. It prevents a branch from being updated by certain users. To update such branch ,you either have to be a role who has more permissions, like Owner, or the branch is unprotected by someone who has the permission.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using **Gitea**. I couldn't read Chinese but the picture was very helpful. > https://brallow.com/?p=679

Just run `Site Administration > Dashboard > Resynchronize pre-receive, update and post-receive hooks of all repositories. > Run`.

Then I can `git push` correctly now!